# Sketchup: Issues healing model

Tags: sketchup

I am working on a model of my local theatre, and I am having some trouble with trying to heal or combine separate shapes.

on the provided image:
I can't seem to heal faces this without deleting the whole arch, or combine the 2 parts of the arch to be as 1.

if I try extending the wall which I want to do, I end up with weird results.

Suggestions please?

Thank you!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Old case, still unsolved.

In SketchUP two parts, which have fitting dimensions, but which are extruded separately in different places, do not become one solid piece if they are placed face to face. They remain separate - no matter how well the faces fit against each other. The legs of your arc should be made by extruding their opponent faces in the arc or the whole piece arc+legs should be extruded as one.

Seemingly you have pure surface parts with no thickness. They behave badly when they meet other parts. Do as told in another answer: Extrude all parts.

The paid version has union tool. I do not know does it remove zero width seams.

Answer (score 0):

I would check 2 things.

- Be sure the normals are oriented the same.
- Be sure all the wall has some "volume", that all pieces are extruded.
- And confirm all faces are coplanar.
- If the faces are deleted anyway, draw them again.